# How to migrate an MVC 4 OpenId Google Login to OAuth 2.0 or Google+ Sign-in

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth, google-openid

I have an MVC 4 web application that is currently using the out-of-the-box OpenId Google Login. This has been deprecated by Google and so, I need to migrate this to one of Google's supported methods. I have read the documentation provided by Google,[OpenID 2.0 (Migration)](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID), but I still am not able to integrate the new login method with my application. 

All I intend to use the Google Login for is the email address. I am not concerned with obtaining any other information from Google about the user. 

**My question is what steps must I take to migrate my MVC 4 web application to a supported method of Google's login?**

Note: While formatting this question I came across this promising information: [Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web_applications)

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is create a MVC project in C#, enable Single Authorization and edit the file Startup.Auth.cs with your info:

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
{
ClientId = "{your ID}",
ClientSecret = "{your client-secret}"
});
```

Comment: I tried installing Dotnetauth for oauth 2. The nuget error message says it is compatible only with .NET 4.5+. Is there a workaround?